# TensorFlow 2 one-hot encoding of labels

Tags: neural-network, keras, tensorflow, one-hot-encoding, convolutional-neural-network

I was following [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/classification) basic TensorFlow Image Classification problem, where images of flowers have to be classified into one of 5 possible classes. The labels in the training set are not one-hot encoded, and are individual numbers: 1,2,3,4 or 5 (corresponding to 5 classes). The final layer of the ConvNet however has `num_class` number of units.

Wouldn't there be a dimension mismatch while computing the loss, since you are finding the difference between a `[num_class, 1]` (predicted label) dimensioned vector and a `[1, 1]` (true label) dimensioned vector?

Does the Keras backend automatically convert the labels into one-hot vectors?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loss function handles the conversion. TensorFlow has a `SparseCategoricalCrossentropy` and a `CategoricalCrossentropy` loss function. The first expect your labels to be provided as integers, where the latter expects one-hot encodings. In the given example, they use the `SparseCategoricalCrossentropy` loss function, therefore it is ok to supply your labels as integers.

Comment: Thank you so much for that pointer! I did not realize that there were two types of these loss functions.